# GoLang correct way of stopping goroutines

Tags: go, goroutine

Does for-select-quit pattern makes sure that all the functions are returned before loop finished.

Consider following code

```
func FnBusy() {
    log.Println("Entering FnBusy")
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Minute)
    log.Println("Exiting FnBusy")
}

func TestGoRoutineStop(t *testing.T) {
    quit := make(chan interface{})
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    ticker := time.NewTicker(10 * time.Millisecond)
    defer ticker.Stop()
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            select {
            case <-quit:
                log.Println("Quit Called")
                return
            case <-ticker.C:
                FnBusy()
            }
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(150 * time.Millisecond)
    close(quit)
    wg.Wait()

}
```

When I run this test I get following output

```
=== RUN   TestGoRoutineStop
2021/09/20 11:03:18 Entering FnBusy
2021/09/20 11:04:18 Exiting FnBusy
2021/09/20 11:04:18 Entering FnBusy
2021/09/20 11:05:18 Exiting FnBusy
2021/09/20 11:05:18 Entering FnBusy
2021/09/20 11:06:18 Exiting FnBusy
2021/09/20 11:06:18 Quit Called
--- PASS: TestGoRoutineStop (180.01s)
```

What I want to understand is when the `close(quit)` is called, and if `FnBusy` in still executing will it wait for it to finish

Comment: Goroutines execute code sequentially.   The `case <- quit` code path will not execute while `FnBusy` is executing.

Comment: FYI - the code you pasted _cannot_ produce the output you pasted, as the `FnBusy` is waiting for one minute and the goroutine in main is waited for 150ms, the loop will terminate after one run of `FnBusy`

Comment: @Inian  It is likely that the ticker and quit channel are ready the second time the select statement is executed.  If the select takes the ticker case, then `FnBusy` will be executed twice.